# Isometric orientation for heatmap with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, isometric

Assume we have a heat-map as below

[image]

construct using the code

```
import string
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
label=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
mdata = np.random.randn(3, len(label), len(label))
data = mdata[0, :, :]
data=np.tril(data,-1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

Is possible whether using Matplotlib, Seaborn or any other package to render into isometric
alignment as below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With matplotlib's [3D toolkit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#bar-plots), and using numpy's [`triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), you could create a bar plot from the triangular matrix:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
N = 26
data = np.random.randn(3, N, N)
for i, (plane, cmap) in enumerate(zip(data, ['Reds', 'Greens', 'Blues'])):
    indices = np.triu_indices(N, 1)
    norm = plt.Normalize(plane.min(), plane.max())
    ax.bar(left=indices[0], bottom=indices[1], height=0.9,
           zs=i, zdir='y',
           color=plt.get_cmap(cmap)(norm(plane[indices])))
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing heatmap in 3D planes]

PS: To have full rectangles, the sub-arrays from `np.indices` need to be made 1D:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
N = 26
data = np.random.randn(3, N, N)
for i, (plane, cmap) in enumerate(zip(data, ['Reds', 'Greens', 'Blues'])):
    indices = np.indices((N,N))
    norm = plt.Normalize(plane.min(), plane.max())
    ax.bar(left=indices[0].ravel(), bottom=indices[1].ravel(), height=0.9,
           zs=i, zdir='y',
           color=plt.get_cmap(cmap)(norm(plane).ravel()))
plt.show()
```

[image: 3D planes of heatmaps]

Comment: Awesome. For the benefit of future reader and mine as well (slightly greedy here).  Do you mind to share the snippet for plotting full array (both the upper and lower tri as shown in the OP figure)

Comment: Hi @JohanC, I change the `triu_indices` into `np.indices((N, N))`, but, to no success. Kindly advice